# converting vba into formula

Tags: vba, excel-formula

What i'd like is that i can put in a excel formula a check to all parameters like this code below. The code runs without error if put it in a loop, but its slow and i have a small data-set (around 1500 records).
what i have similar to this is a code that put "formula.local" values on a predefine table (so it auto-completes).

Bottom line i really need this code to runs faster... If there is a way to put it like a "local.formula", or even improve the code itself to run faster please let me know.
If this is not clear please tell me and i'll try to explain better.
Thanks.

```
If comp = "AC" Then
Cells(i, 77).Value = "AC"
GoTo nextrec
End If
If state = "idle" Then
    If resp >= obj Then
        'idle but already miss deadline
        Cells(i, 77).Value = "idle miss"
    Else
    'idle but ok 
        Cells(i, 77).Value = "idle"
    End If
Else
'ended
    If resp >= obj Then
        'ended miss deadline
        Cells(i, 77).Value = "ended missed"
    Else
        'deadline ok 
        Cells(i, 77).Value = "ended ok"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Why not just use `IF` in formula?

Comment: Also, no need for the `End If` way of doing it, it's just `if....else...` like the 2nd part

Comment: Your code is incomplete. We cannot help on just a snippet of your code. What is `state`, `resp`, `obj`? Where is `nextrec`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav my problem is that i cant build the if formula to check all those settings, allways something missing

Comment: i tryed to simplify the best i can ..     fields status1 - can be "idle" or "processing"::: status2  - can be "missed" or "ok":::::  finally i need to add a column to have the values "idle but missed" "; idle ok" ; "ended missed"; "ended ok "

Comment: @user2798634 so you cant do the formula, but you've had a go at the code?  `If(x=1,if(y=1,2,3),if(z=1,4,5),6)`  it would be along this sort of syntax

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single excel formula without the need for VBA.  The following formula should accomplish what your code does.

Since you didn't provide a snip of sample data I'm going to assume that `comp, state, resp, obj` are values from other columns of the same row.  You can replace these values in my formula with the corresponding cell reference then drag down.

```
=IF(comp="AC",
    "AC",
    IF(state="idle",
          IF(resp>=obj,"idle miss","idle"),
          IF(resp>=obj,"ended miss","ended ok")
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

@DavidN spot on , it is exactly how i need it ...for some reason i was not handling the multiple if statement the right way , i googled some examples but i just got even more messed up. has always the right way is the simple way. thanks.